# Long running background task on startup in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis

I've got a web application that is connected to a SqlServer instance. The data in the database comes from a few files in a folder on the server. On startup the Application check if there are any changes in the files, and if there are the data in SqlServer is deleted, the data is processed and then written to the database. Fairly basic.

The processing and writing of the data can take up to 45 minutes, so I want to use a background thread to make the rest of the application usable. The import has to be mostly sequential, because data from different files depends on each other. The problem with this, is that the thread is killed after about 20 minutes. I've tried `Task.Run, Thread, ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem, HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkitem` but all seem to have this problem. The problem seems to be the timeout of IIS, which kills the thread after a X amount of time after the initial request is fired.

I've found a lot of people having kind of the same problem, but most of them have **recurring** long running tasks, or requests that are actually depended on these tasks. I've looked into `HangFire`, but that seems a bit overkill, for just a import task on startup.

Is there a simple solution to this problem or do I need to rethink the way the application handles the importing of these files?

Comment: It is not the thread which is killed - it is the application process itself

Comment: I would imagine a solution where you trigger off changes to a standby database and poll for a signal and switch over from your current live database could provide a more reliable process.

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes - start reading at **Idle Time-Out**

Comment: Hangfire itself won't solve your problem, though [some documentation on their site would have](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html). Anyways, this work sounds like it should not be in your web application to begin with. Sounds like it's better suited to a Windows Service or a Scheduled Task.

Comment: @SirRufo This would solve my problem for the time being. But if the files keep growing, I'd have to increase the Idle Time-Out each time. But for now it solves my problem thanks!

Comment: @mason I was affraid this would be the best option. I was hoping that there was something I overlooked.

Comment: You shouldn't be afraid of it - it's the right thing to do. It will keep you from using up threads your website would otherwise be able to use. And the work is probably of a different nature than just servicing HTTP requests, so it will scale differently. Tools like TopShelf and Hangfire make it pretty easy, or you can implement bus messages via RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus or MassTransit.